# GLUT - Undefined reference to pressedButton(int, int)

Tags: c++, glut, freeglut

I have a `main` method that contains the `glutMotionFunc` that receives the function `movimentoMouseBotaoApertado` that the signature is `void movimentoMouseBotaoApertado(int, int)`. I have a `.h` and `.cpp` file, but when I import the `.h` at the main file and try to execute the code, the error appears `undefined reference to movimentoMouseBotaoApertado(int, int)`

### main.cpp

```
...
#include "mouse/mouse.h"
#include "desenha/desenha.h"
...
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv); // Always needs glutInit
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);

    inicializa();
    nomeDoPrograma();

    glutDisplayFunc(desenha);
    glutKeyboardFunc(teclado);
    glutSpecialFunc(teclasEspeciais);
    criarMenu();
    glutMouseFunc(gerenciaMouse);
    glutMotionFunc(movimentoMouseBotaoApertado);
    glutPassiveMotionFunc(movimentoMouse);
    glutReshapeFunc(alterarTamanhoJanela);
    glutMainLoop(); // Redesenhando
}
```

### movimentoMouseBotaoApertado.h

```
#ifndef MOVIMENTOMOUSEBOTAOAPERTADO_H_INCLUDED
#define MOVIMENTOMOUSEBOTAOAPERTADO_H_INCLUDED

void movimentoMouseBotaoApertado(int, int);

#endif // MOVIMENTOMOUSEBOTAOAPERTADO_H_INCLUDED
```

### movimentoMouseBotaoApertado.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>

void movimentoMouseBotaoApertado(int x, int y) {
    printf("Botão apertado [%d,%d]", x, y);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I clicked with the right button and selected *Add files recursively...* and I chose the folders/files and worked it.